# Rails - Creating a custom ERB tag for i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Since I write so often this in Rails...

```
<%= t 'whatever' %>
```

I was wondering: Is it possible to create a custom tag to make it even shorter? Something like...

```
<%t 'whatever' %>
```

It would be fun if I could create my custom tags and make them output anything based on its content.

How would such a thing be doable?

PS: I realize that I am just saving just 1 character. As I said it is for fun. And besides, if creating custom tags is not too complicated, it could have even more applications.

Comment: I'd rather look at using slim or haml, that way you can safe many characters, not just one :)

Comment: Is a nice idea. I might look into rails functionality if I have some time. But I doubt that I will come up with an immediate solution.  ^^

Comment: I don't know how one would do this, or how hard it would be to figure out ... but I'd strongly recommend *not* doing this for a number of reasons. Put simply, you are adding surprising custom behaviour with negligible benefits, and all sorts of major potential drawbacks. As @Iceman said: If you'd like to make the code a little shorter, just use [HAML](http://haml.info/) or [SLIM](http://slim-lang.com/) instead of ERB.

Comment: Is worth the trouble just to save one character per line? Think that all your view files will not be the conventional way of doing rails, thus adding maintenance complexity.

Comment: I was asking JUST FOR FUN :) Just to know if it is doable

Comment: At a very quick glance, it looks like you'd need to do some dirty monkeypatching of [this file](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/erb.rb) to make it work... Of course it's possible, but I don't really fancy investing the time to work out how to do it ;)